# Server Side and Client Side communications Functions with values at Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform

Here's the problem...

I saw [this post](https://yagisanatode.com/2018/06/10/google-apps-script-getting-input-data-from-a-dialog-box-in-google-sheets/) on the internet, and this is very useful for my day job.
so I adapted the code to do what I need.

The problem: in Client Side, I need to show form and the Server Side made the rest of the code, just receiving the values from the client. note: The client-side can't change code from the Script Editor tool.

See the screenshots below to fully understand.

**Server Side - Code**

[image: Server Side Code]

**Server Side - Form (HTML View)**
[image]

**Server Side - Form (Script Code in HTML to read Values)** - *similar to the post from Yagisanatode*
[image]

**Server Side - Logger values**
[image]

until here, everything works perfectly,
the problem comes when I try to import it to the client Side.

**Client-Side - Library Import**

[image]

**Client Side - Code**

[image]

**Client Side - Form (HTML View)**
[image]

all seems to be working. but when the client hit de submit button.
NOTHING WORKS! the function addRegistro(values) on the client-side don't run. also don't run on the server-side!

so, I appreciate the help from the community, to understand why this happens. what I doing wrong?

Comment: [Edit] to provide code as plain text instead of a image.

Comment: If(!postedCode)let help=false;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change  button type from submit to button. it works.

Comment: It does not work for me, runsies() function is never triggered. What canI change to make the example to work?

Comment: the Google Apps Script editor has recently been updated. in the legacy version the example above works normally. in the new version, it is necessary to deploy the server side, and on the client side, configure the library as the latest version.
developer mode does not work correctly for the example above.
  the problem has already been reported to google through issueTracker 176214022

Answer (score 1):

I bet your problem is in the "novoRegistro" function. The function in the library is probably not accessing the current spreadsheet. Google documentation about spreadsheetapp.getUI says "A script can only interact with the UI for the current instance of an open spreadsheet, and only if the script is bound to the spreadsheet.".
Try to put the function "novoRegistro"  in your application .gs code instead of the library.

Comment: The function getUI return to user who call it, so even in the server side, it works, because the client call the function, so the current Ui, is Ui from client. It won't work if my ServerSide is linked with a Spreadsheet, but in my case, the Server side is a Script Stand Alone.